# Showing/hiding <div> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fadein, fadeout

For example I have a function called `showcontainer`. When I click on a button activating it, I want a certain div element, in this case `<div id="container">`, to fade in. And when I click it again, fade out.
How do I achieve this?

Note: I am not accustomed with jQuery.

Comment: as in 'don't want to use jquery'? the functionality you are asking for is easy in jquery (and probably a bunch of other similar frameworks) - not so in plain javascript.

Comment: The functionality you're asking is trivial with jQuery.  What's your view on it?  You don't want to use it or you don't know how to use it?

Comment: @froderik that is why I noted that I don't know jQuery. I asked because I have seen a bit of the library, but I still don't know.

Comment: @AleksG Don't know, want help.

Comment: Okay, got the `container` to fade in or out when I click the button. How do I make it be faded out straight away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you're not opposed to using jQuery per se, you can achieve this easily:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showcontainer').click(function() {
            $('#container').fadeToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
...
<div id="container">
...
</div>
...

<input type="button" id="showcontainer" value="Show/hide"/>
...
```

Note the missing `http:` in the beginning of the source of jQuery.  With this trick the browser will automatically use `http:` or `https:` based on whether the original page is secure.

The piece of code after including jQuery assigns the handler to the button.

Comment: How can I make the container be already faded out (no fade, just not faded out yet)?

Comment: I you want to start with the div not visible, just use css to set its initial `display` to `none`.  Put in your css: `#container { display: none;}`

Comment: Works fine, going great. Final product: http://jsfiddle.net/Dann/YFRtm/ _Click 'Add'_

Answer (score 2):

So you got a bunch of jQuery answers. That's fine, I tend to use jQuery for this kind of stuff too. But doing that in plain JavaScript is not hard, it's just a lot more verbose:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var btn = document.getElementById('showcontainer');

btn.onclick = function() {

    // Fade out
    if(container.style.display != 'none') {
      var fade = setInterval(function(){
        var opacity = parseFloat(container.style.opacity);
        opacity = isNaN(opacity) ? 100 : parseInt(opacity * 100, 10);
        opacity -= 5;
        container.style.opacity = opacity/100;
        if(opacity <= 0) {
          clearInterval(fade);
          container.style.opacity = 0;
          container.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }, 50);

    // Fade in
    } else {
      container.style.display = 'block';
      container.style.opacity = 0;
      var fade = setInterval(function(){
        var opacity = parseFloat(container.style.opacity);
        opacity = isNaN(opacity) ? 100 : parseInt(opacity * 100, 10);
        opacity += 5;
        container.style.opacity = opacity/100;
        if(opacity >= 100) {
          clearInterval(fade);
          container.style.opacity = 1;
        }
      }, 50);
    }

};
```

Check the [working demo](http://jsbin.com/oroqod/2/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Best thing you could do is start now and get accustomed to jQuery.

The page http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ has all the example code that could be written here. Basically you want to have the call to fadeIn in your showcontainer function.

```
function showcontainer() {
    $('#container').fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [jQuery UI Toggle](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/).

The documentation turns the use of the library very simple, and they have many code examples.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be as well off learning jQuery as it makes it a lot easier to do things!

From the sounds of it, you could have the container div already in the HTML but with a style of "display:none;", and then simply show it in your click event using ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)):

```
$('#container').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    //Any additional logic after it's visible can go here
  });
```